# prolog - out of local stack error

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a program that has following specifications:

```
N=int
X=int
R=list containing N copies of X
• R=[] if N=0
• N will always be given
• Either X or R will be given
```

Example results:

```
?- fill(4,2,R). 
R=[2,2,2,2].
?- fill(4,X,[2,2,2,2]). 
X=2.
```

I have the following code that gives me 'out of local stack error' when I run the first fill statement. What's causing it?

```
fill(0,_,[]).
fill(N,X,R) :- N1 is N-1, fill(N1,X,R), append(R,[X], R).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is: the second claused is used even if N=0.

This leads to a chain of calls fill(0,...) => fill(-1,....) => fill(-2, ....) => ....

Remedy: Adding a cut to the first clause should avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. I've added N>0 to the second clause. However, How do I get R to return at the end? I just get 'false' when I run it.

Comment: Using twice `R` in `append(R,[X],R].`, as input and ouput data, seems inappropriate. Shouln't it be `fill(N,X,R) :- N1 is N-1, fill(N1,X,R1), append(R1,[X], R).` ?

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense. now it gives me the correct output. Thanks.